# Возможно ли в цикл for вставить prompt?

Tags: javascript

К примеру:

```
for (let i = prompt("Введите число не ниже 100", 0); i <= 100 && i;) 
{
  alert (i);
}
```

Можно сделать через do...while, но хочется больше примеров изложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ЛЮБОЙ цикл while можно переписать в for, и наоборот.

```js
let i = prompt("Число"); 

while(i && +i <= 100){
  alert (i);
  i = prompt("Число");
}
```

↓ ↓ ↓

```js
for (let i = prompt("Число"); i && +i <= 100; i = prompt("Число")) {
  alert (i);
}
```

Но конкретно для этой задачи, решение в форме while более привычное.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что оставил переменные с другого кода. Только увидел.
Спасибо за разъяснение.
Получается в такие случаи лучше использовать схему do...while? Более удобно.